# Pandas, create a column value, based on dataintervals

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm rather new to python, and have a panda containing data, that needs a labelling, based on their time of acquisition. 
The panda has a timestamp column, containing timestamps of type `datetime64`.

I want to evaluate all values in the column, and test wether they are within a certain range of time, and from this assign a label 1-5, in a new column, based on what interval the date falls within.

```
timestamp:             interval:
2017-03-22 13:12:00     1
2017-03-23 13:12:00     1
2017-03-24 13:12:00     2
2017-03-25 13:12:00     2
2017-03-26 13:12:00     2
```

i have tried a function, that can be called with a dataframe like below

```
def classifyRunHours(series):
    if [(series['index_time'] > PERIOD_1) & (series['index_time'] <= PERIOD_2)]:
        return 1
    elif [(series['index_time'] > PERIOD_2) & (series['index_time'] <= PERIOD_3)]:
        return 2
    elif [(series['index_time'] > PERIOD_3) & (series['index_time'] <= PERIOD_4)]:
        return 3
    elif [(series['index_time'] > PERIOD_4) & (series['index_time'] <= PERIOD_5)]:
        return 4
    else:
        return 0
```

And having intervals defined as

```
PERIOD_1 = '2017-05-20 11:00:00'
```

This gives me some trouble since im comparing a string and a timestamp.
That might be solvable, but im not sure if this is the right way to work on a column. Should i use a `lambda` function, to work on the entire column ? or how can this be done efficiently

Any inputs are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) + [`add_categories`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cat.add_categories.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace `NaN`s:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=15)
series = pd.DataFrame({'index_time': rng, 'a': range(15)})  

PERIOD_1 = '2017-04-05'
PERIOD_2 = '2017-04-08'
PERIOD_3 = '2017-04-10'
PERIOD_4 = '2017-04-11'
PERIOD_5 = '2017-04-13'

bins = pd.DatetimeIndex([PERIOD_1,PERIOD_2,PERIOD_3,PERIOD_4, PERIOD_5])
labels = [1,2,3,4]
series['interval'] = pd.cut(series['index_time'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
series['interval'] = series['interval'].cat.add_categories([0]).fillna(0)
print (series)
     a index_time interval
0    0 2017-04-03        0
1    1 2017-04-04        0
2    2 2017-04-05        0
3    3 2017-04-06        1
4    4 2017-04-07        1
5    5 2017-04-08        1
6    6 2017-04-09        2
7    7 2017-04-10        2
8    8 2017-04-11        3
9    9 2017-04-12        4
10  10 2017-04-13        4
11  11 2017-04-14        0
12  12 2017-04-15        0
13  13 2017-04-16        0
14  14 2017-04-17        0
```

Another solution with [`searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
bins = pd.DatetimeIndex(['1678-01-01',PERIOD_1,PERIOD_2,PERIOD_3,PERIOD_4, PERIOD_5, '2226-01-01'])
labels = [0,1,2,3,4,0]
series['interval'] = np.array(labels)[np.array(bins).searchsorted(series['index_time'].values) - 1]
print (series)
     a index_time  interval
0    0 2017-04-03         0
1    1 2017-04-04         0
2    2 2017-04-05         0
3    3 2017-04-06         1
4    4 2017-04-07         1
5    5 2017-04-08         1
6    6 2017-04-09         2
7    7 2017-04-10         2
8    8 2017-04-11         3
9    9 2017-04-12         4
10  10 2017-04-13         4
11  11 2017-04-14         0
12  12 2017-04-15         0
13  13 2017-04-16         0
14  14 2017-04-17         0
```

Comment: `cut` + `add_categories` with fillna  did the trick, quite smooth, as i was hoping for, would be possible with pandas. Sweet that the binning can be done with `datetime`directly.
I am still a bot confused on quite when regular and sharp brackets are used for indexing, hopefully that will clear, as experience is gained, thanks